# Flash Settings & Android Gaming

Tags: android, flash

I'm working on a project that will help arcade flash gamers [play within an Android](http://android-free-games.com/) flash supported browser. Is there a jquery or similar open-source script that helps flash enter full screen easily no matter the size of the flash game? If not what php or java-script functions can I use to accomplish this? The problem is our flash games are in different sizes and I would like to have all sizes enter full screen.

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably have to write your own.

For a commercial project I immitated a fullscreen mode by scaling the flash container to 100%.
Not that hard, 20 minutes max.